# Nuance of almost not

Tags: word-usage

Does the sentence “*For him, ten years can scarcely suffice to realize the project.*” mean that there is a low, or very low, probability off his realizing the project?

When I say “low or very low probabilities”, I mean something like a 1% or 2% probability.

Comment: It’s not a matter of probability. It’s stated as a matter of fact, as Kate Bunting noted in your other question.

Comment: but i think it imply that is unlikely to realize that thing in ten years....or it is very likely to realize that thing in more than ten years...in that way it is a question of probability?

Comment: Andrew Bumetsov leave that coment-,It is possible to realize in ten years only if you are super cool, gifted, etc. It may take more than 10 years, moreover, it is very likely to be so'- it is a wright answer?

Comment: This is a very odd sentence. Where did you find it?

Comment: is not a certain context,is just something general..

Comment: I don't understand whether this is a sentence you are quoting from someone else's writings, or whether you have written it yourself.

Comment: i wrote alone these sentence

Comment: Electro22, if something scarcely suffices, that means it is only just enough. There is no 'chance' about it. It _is_ enough. If I owe $100, and I have $150, that will comfortably suffice to pay my debt; if I have $100.05, that will scarcely suffice.

Comment: He needs more than 10 years to finish the project. So, would that time suffice? In a word - no, but maybe at low probability - yes. I hear *scarcely* to mean more no than yes. @MichaelHarvey I see $100.05 as sufficing for $100, but $90, no.

Comment: Yosef Baskin, if ten years suffice, ten years are enough. He does not need more than 10 years. To suffice is to _be enough_.

Comment: but scarcely not mean certainly yes...

Comment: Scarcely enough means narrowly enough, almost not enough, only just enough. All of these mean "enough".

Comment: Note that there is an implied speaker saying “For him, ten years can scarcely suffice to realize the project.” This means that **_the speaker considers_** that there is a very small probabliity of the person mentioned completing the project within the ten years specified. The speaker could have said "With him in charge, ten years is hardly likely to be nearly enough."